# How to achieve Windows Phone 8 News App layout

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I am wondering how does the News app on Windows Phone achieve its layout. I am taking about the main page when the app is first launched. It is not a pivot because you can see the next section on the current section. It is not a panorama because the background is not moving, and that it is a universal app so Panorama is not available. It is not a Hub because Hub does not allow you to wrap from the first to last, or vice versa.

I notice this layout is very similar, almost identical to the layout of the Fitbit app. I like this kind of layout a lot and I would like to use that on my own app. If there is a control for it please let me know, if not, how do I do what the developer have done on those apps.

Comment: It is a modified panorama.  The app doesn't have a background image, so it doesn't move.  It can't be an universal app because it ran on WP8 (it could be now, but the layout hasn't changed).  If you learn to modify the default template for the panorama it is very easy to achieve.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware It should be a universal app because if you search the app in the app store, it shows the desktop/mobile icon. I thought that meant the app is a universal app.

Comment: There might be different versions of the app, but it did run on Windows Phone 8 so that was before universal apps.  An universal app is not what you think it is.. it is just a project with 3 different solutions... (it's really ghetto).  Most of the time you end up coding 2 different layouts and it only saves you time because they can share some basic classes.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware The app I have should be the universal version. If the app targets universal, there won't be a panorama control available. So there is no way it's a panorama if it targets universal, unless they recoded it again. The hub control is really similar to panorama but I don't like how it works visually on the Phone.

Comment: I'm not saying they didn't update it to 8.1 runtime, I'm saying it runs on WP8.0 .. check their page http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/news/9c3e8cad-6702-4842-8f61-b8b33cc9caf1, mostly likely still a WP8.0 Silverlight application, with the desktop version being a separate Hub style.

Answer (score 0):

The app is using the Panorama/Hub control. It does not set the title of the control and it does not have an image for it. The first Page/Section does have an image for the main article. this image is only set for that Page/Section. The first section also does not have a Header set (it's blank).

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is what I would have guessed for a Silverlight app, where Panorama is available. I thought this is a universal app and the Hub control on phone acts differently than what I observe in the News app. The Hub control has "unpleasant" (to me) animation when you are panning on the to the right on the first or panning to the left on the last section of the Hub, making me not want to use the Hub control. If I am making a universal app and wanting to achieve this layout without Hub, or with Hub modified, how would I approach it?

Comment: You mean the snap that the Hub does? I think the News app is still a Silverlight app

Comment: Yes, the snapping that the Hub does. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: There might be, but it would be a lot of work. Not sure it's worth it. Using Runtime XAML is best approach for moving code forward, but you can always use Silverlight still